# IBKCart javascript works/doesn't

Tags: javascript, php

```
                         <div class="insideContQty"><strong>' . $this->getCartItems() . '</strong> item'. $plural .' in your cart <a href="#" class="block" onclick="if(confirm(\'Are you sure?\')){doCart(\'EmptyCart\', \'' . 0 . '\', 0, \'ChkOut\');} ">Empty Cart </a><br />
                      &nbsp;</div>
```

"doCart" in the above code works to empty a shopping cart from within the class IBKCart (CSS IBKcart an open source cart), but when I code into the module "partCheckOut.php" as below it does not empty the cart:

```
              <?php 
                if ($Cart->getCartItems() == 0){ 
                    $Cart->DisplayEmptyCart('ChkOut') ;
                } else { 
                    echo $Cart->DisplayCheckOut();
                }
                //if(isset($_POST["confirm"]))
                if (isset($_POST['confirm']))
                { 
                    $Cart->ConfirmOrder();
                    $Cart->sendOrderEmails($dealer_email);  
                    echo "doCart(\'EmptyCart\', \'' . 0 . '\', 0, \'ChkOut\');";
```

The call to the javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js_IBKCart/ShoppingCart.js"></script>
```

is at the top of the html, and above the function call to "doCart"

I have tried both the "echo 'doCart(...)'" and doCart(...) as recommended in stackoverflow but have been unable to spot the problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to take a look at your source code generated.
I don't know if the echo you show there is printing this without being inside of script tag.
One solution may be to replace that echo with the following:

`echo "<script>doCart(\\'EmptyCart\\', \\'' . 0 . '\\', 0, \\'ChkOut\\');</script>";`

Notice that i doubled the backslashes here in order to generate exactly what your onclick does.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and it also did not empty the cart. How would I look at the source code generated?

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion to see what source is generated. I was linking back to a menu and the code generated was disappearing. I took out the link and 2 notices became visible which will help me to de-bug. It is not the code but a problem with undefined variables. I will put it down as solved.